# Serverless Framework - Reference Layer sans version, or always latest version

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a layer defined in a separate file from any functions, and my functions are dependent upon the layer.

If I deploy the layer, I get a new version number for the layer and I have to redeploy all items dependent on the layer to use the new layer version.

Is there a way for a function to reference the separately-defined layer generally, without a version number, or for the function to always reference the latest version?

Below is the `serverless.yaml` that defines the layer (with a few substitutions in brackets).

```
service: layer-dev-npm

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: us-east-1
  profile: [profile-name]
  deploymentBucket:
    name: [bucket-name]

layers:
  LayerDevNPM:
    path: nodejs
    description: "npm dependencies"
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: HI, I think you can use the `Ref` to get the `arn` by name e.g `{Ref: LayerDevNPM}` . Also, why you want to remove the layer instead of update the code? 
Thx!

Comment: @pepo, thanks for your comment. My understanding is that I could only use {Ref: LayerDevNPM} if the Layer were defined in the same file in which it is referenced. My Layers are defined in separate files (updated post to reflect this). If I'm wrong, then I'd love to see an example or explanation as to how to do this.

Comment: Hi @skip, I think you can use `Fn::ImportValue` for that, but you need to be sure that the other stacks are exporting the values that you need ( e.g the layers ).
Some link to docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/list-exports.html

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you will deploy your template it will create new version for layer also.
So, i will suggest deploy layer separately and then later use the version in lambda like this.

`layers:
    - arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:layer:layerName:1(layer version)`